# Exception handling (I want to check if the connection.Open() runs)

Tags: c#, exception

I'd like my code to give a warning or something whenever the database is not available.
(That's why I commented the connection string), but my website just crashes.

I created this class cause there were many parts of the program using this connection string (login page, register page, user panel page, etc), so if I want to change something in the future, this is the only string I have to change.

```
namespace Fatture.Data.User
{
   public class DbConnection
   {
      public MySqlConnection ConnessioneDb()
      {
         MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(/*ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringloginDb"].ConnectionString*/);
         try
         {
            conn.Open();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            throw new Exception("I can't connect to the database", ex);               

         }
         return conn;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You're throwing a new Exception that is likely never caught.

Comment: Why do you throw a new exception?  Where do you handle that exception?  If the exception is unhandled then yes the application will crash.

Comment: What is the exact problem?  What does "my website just crashes" mean?  Do you have any application-level error handling?

Comment: don't just throw the exception catch it somewhere and then show user the appropriate message.

Comment: @RohitGupta Or use the exception that has already been thrown. Chaining thrown exceptions seems like a horrific idea.

Comment: Meh I'm new to exceptions, I messed it up. Regarding to my code, should I look forward about how to catch an exception?

Comment: @GinoPerla To me, the way you caught the exception is actually fine. But `catch` blocks are usually meant for giving feedback to the user of why their action failed, and for us programmers to properly debug. You'd be better off to do something like `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message())`, as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exception handling...

```
var connector = new DbConnection();

try
{       
    var connection = connector.ConnessioneDb();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // show message to user: database not available
}
```

Though you'll have to put this in place everywhere you access the database. Instead you can also just set up error handling for your entire site.

Answer (score 1):

Catch the exception...

```
try
{       
    var conn =  new DbConnection().ConnessioneDb();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     // Notify user here
}
```

Comment: why do you say that ? Just because I posted after you ?

Comment: Guys, the answers are 3 min apart, that is well within the time it could take to write up the code (if you had to do a MSDN lookup or two). You don't see new answers while you are typing automaticly, if I had been typing an answer my answer would look like these two too.

Comment: I just don't get it what is the big deal :\

Comment: Sure, I don't want to falsely accuse you, nevermind.